# Как сменить пароль postgres пользователя?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql9.6

Команда `ALTER USER owr WITH PASSWORD 'owrPASSWORD';` не помогает.

При входе `psql -W -U owr` получаю ошибку `psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "owr"`

Пробовал разное из интернетов, но ничего не помогало.

Answer (score 3):

`psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "owr"`

Данная ошибка говорит о том, что пользователя **owr** на сервере (а не в БД) не существует, так используется способ **peer** для подключения к БД, который в качестве пользователей базы данных для аутентификации использует пользователей, которые уже существует в самой ОС.

В данном же случае необходимо использовать способ **password**, дабы появилась возможность задавать пароль при входе в БД. Всё это настраивается в файле *pg_hba.conf*, в Debian, например, он находится по такому пути:

```
/etc/postgresql/9.4/main
```

В котором необходимо исправить данную строчку:

```
local   all             all                                     peer
```

на

```
local   all             all                                     password
```

После этого применяем новые настройки: `sudo service postgresql reload`